# "Fixing" sigil counter stacks

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've reported this as a bug already, but I was wondering if anyone has any tips.

I use a Sigil of Luck when trying to farm around.  When the going gets tough, I'd like to switch to a Sigil of Corruption.  Unfortunately, it seems like once I already have a counter for Luck and switch weapons to the Sigil of Corruption..... I continue to gain Luck counters.  If I main-hand the Sigil of Luck weapon and off-hand the Corruption weapon - I gain only corruption counters.

The only way I know to fix this is to get knocked down or to fast travel - neither one is ideal.

Also, if any engineers are reading this, be aware that Kit/Turrent/Golem kills do not count toward sigils unless you get the last hit with the sigil weapon. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigil stacks are limited, you can only get stacks for one type at once. The way it SHOULD work is replace the stack with the new type, not keep adding to it.